# Generate complete sequence giving min and max value in SAS?

Tags: sas

So my data looks something like this

```
OBS _Seq_ 
1  15
2  16
3  20
4  22
```

I want a new data set that have a complete sequence of *Seq*. So something like this:

```
OBS _Seq_ 
1  15
2  16
3  17
4  18
5  19
6  20
7  21
8  22
```

I tried.

```
data _null_;
set data;
%let minSeq = min(_Seq_);
%let maxSeq = max(_Seq_);
run;

data newSeq;
do sequence = &minSeq to &maxSeq;
output;
end;
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to assign a data step value to a macro variable, you need to use `call symput`. `_n_=1` is true when the first row is read, and `eof` (initialized by the `end=` option in the `set` statement) signifies the last row of the data set. So assuming your data is sorted by `_seq_`:

```
data _null_;
  set data end=eof;
  if _n_=1 then call symput('minSeq',put(_Seq_,20.));
  if eof   then call symput('maxSeq',put(_Seq_,20.));
run;
```